# ios SDK 4.3 on Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have upgraded to Xcode 4.2 Beta with iOS SDK 5, however, it turned out that the apps built in SDK 5 are not accepted by app store, although the target is set to be 4.0.

Since sdk 4.3 seems to be downloaded with Xcode 4, but I still want to keep the newer Xcode, how can I import SDK 4.3 in Xcode 4.2?

(I tried to reinstall the Xcode 4 with SDK 4.3, but a lot of crashes and errors with no luck. I am also on iTune 10.5.)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to install Xcode 4.0 (release) in addition to Xcode 4.2 beta.

Try deleting the directories for both, and re-installing...

Since we can't really talk about 4.2 because of the NDA, try asking over at the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Thanks! I have installed 2 xcodes in different directories, and so far it is working.

Comment: It's not the case after Mac OS X 10.7.2 : I couldn't install XCode 4.0.2 because installer report versions incompatibility.

Comment: That's an incompatibility with Lion, not an issue with multiple versions of XCode - you can still install XCode 4.1 and 4.2 side by side (though currently there is no reason why you would want to).

Answer (score 0):

I myself run both 'next to each other'. I have the latest official xCode installed under `/Developer` and downloaded the latest BETA version which I installed to `/Developer/iOSBETA`. For updates on old apps I use the official release, archive and release to the AppStore. For new and ongoing projects I use the BETA. This way you have the best of both worlds, in my opinion.